# Parsing Smarty syntax subset in PHP

Tags: php, html, templates, syntax, smarty

For a project I'm working on, I need to parse a tiny flow-control language in PHP.

Smarty syntax would be ideal, but we wouldn't be able to use Smarty's caching and would only need a small subset of it's features (basically just `{if}`,  `{else}`,  `{elseif}`,  `{/if}` and function plugins).

Despite the lack of caching, performance is a major factor; including the entire Smarty framework and disabling caching is too slow.

Is there any PHP framework that can handle Smarty-like syntax without any of the more advanced features. Doesn't need to be a perfect match or even a close match, just something I can mix with plain HTML.

Any code that parses and handles the `if .. elseif .. else ..` logic would be appreciated too; I can hack in the rest myself.

Forgot to mention earlier; the templates are editable by users, so security is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Since all template languages will compile to PHP anyway and speed is a factor why not use embedded PHP statements? It's as fast as can get and won't need any third party hocus pocus.</strike>

*PHP is a templating language to start with*

```
<div>
    <?php if (true): ?>
        <h1>It's true</h1>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h1>It's false</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Since users can edit the templates the above won't be much of an option. The freedom to do whatever you wan't is a huge security risk. So you'll need a templating engine to restrict what's possible.

I always found [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to be a very good templating engine. It's pretty fast without caching and easy to include in your project. Definitely worth a look.

With Twig it's also possible to sandbox your users templates with the sandbox extension.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#sandbox-extension

Comment: Can't use PHP because of security; the templates are supposed to be editable by users.

Comment: Could you explain your security concerns? It's just as secure as any other PHP code.

Comment: I accidentally pressed the [Enter] key before finishing my entire comment, it's now edited to explain. Basically; editable by users.

Comment: Since users can edit the templates everything changes. You should have mentioned it in your question. I updated my answer. Hope it's useful to you.